# Disk Space Issue Installing SQL2008 SP1

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install SQL 2008 SP1 on our SQL2008 server. This server has very little disk space available on the C drive. SQL 2008 is installed on the D drive. I only have about 1.5GB available space on C. I downloaded SP1 to the D drive, I installed from the D drive, and YET, the installer runs my C drive out of space. I started looking into what it was doing, and it looks like it's writing over 1.5 GB of log files to the Windows\System32\LogFiles directory.

How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should try serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: quite a few times when running a MS installer i have noticed that if i have a external hard drive (including USB pen drive) attached then the installer will write its temporary files to it during the install process, the installer must actually be looking for that type of drive.

Another option is to copy some larger folders from your C drive to your D, and then create a symlink on the C drive to replace the folder you just copied - the OS will treat the symlink'ed folder exactly as if it was still a local folder. I have used this technique in the past when drives are running out of space and extending partitions was not an option.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. I had not heard of symlink on the Windows platform. Turns out there is something called "Junction" from the Sys Internals gang. Works on NTFS partitions as well.

Thanks, this will solve LOTS of other problems for me as well!